# How to test Component which requires hook using react testing library?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, testing, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I have built a component which requires a methods and data supplied by custom hook

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const { data, methods } = useMyCustomHook({ defaultValues: defaultValues });

  return <MyAnotherComponent data={data} label="Some Text" method={methods} />;
}
```

I am writing test using react testing library to test `MyComponent` or to be more specific to test `MyAnotherComponent`

Here is my testing code

```
test("Test MyAnotherComponent Label", () => {
  const { data, methods } = useMyCustomHook({ defaultValues: defaultValues });
  render(
    <MyAnotherComponent
      data={data}
      label="Some Text"
      method={methods}
    />
  );
  expect(screen.getByLabelText("Some Text")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

My testcase fails with an error saying `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons`

I have looked up for solutions but some are too simple and some are too complex. Thanks in advance

Comment: Error seems pretty self-explanatory, no? You're calling a hook outside the body of a function component in your test case. Just render the component.

Comment: Rendering the component doesn't work either.  It will cause useContext error in the test. I'm working through this myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact that you are calling the hook inside a function, not inside a React component.
Since you only want to test MyAnotherComponent, I don't see why you'd need to call the hook and not mock the `data` and `methods` directly to pass them to MyAnotherComponent because what you are currently doing is to re-write `MyComponent`.